# How to find oracle database installation path on solaris 8?

Tags: solaris, oracle-11g

I have a server that solaris 8 is on it. I want to connect to oracle's management system . I found this article [getting started with oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10742/em_manage.htm) . To connect to management system I should enter `http://hostname:portnumber/em` on my computer . But I don't have the port.
And the port number also recorded in the `$ORACLE_HOME/install/portlist.ini` file. So How to find this file ?

Comment: You give the path to the file, then say that you can't find it. What exactly is the issue? Is $ORACLE_HOME defined correctly?

Comment: I can not find $ORACLE_HOME

Answer (score 3):

On UNIX systems, if you do not specify the Oracle home directory during installation, the installer attempts to obtain it from information contained in the Oracle installation's **oratab** file, which it locates using the environment variable `ORATAB_LOCATION`. If `ORATAB_LOCATION` does not exist, the installer then attempts to find the file using the standard pathnames

> /etc/oratab

and

> /var/opt/oracle/oratab.

If the installer cannot locate the oratab file using either of these methods, it cannot determine the Oracle_home directory. In this case, you must specify the Oracle home directory and oratab file by setting the `OracleHome` and `OratabLocation` inivars manually by using the `set inivar` configuration command or by editing their definitions in the **init.cfg** file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the name of the file, you can use the good old `find` command, which should be in Solaris as well:

```
find / -type f -name "portlist.ini"
```

Or any other file that you would expect to be there. This should allow you to find the installation path.